# C++ reading file, putting each line in array, doing something with each variable

Tags: c++

Trying to C++ reading file, putting each line in array, doing something with each variable

All it does is save the last line of the file

```
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
 #include <algorithm>
 #include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    std::ifstream the_file("example.txt");

    std::string s;
    std::vector<std::string> lines;
    while (std::getline(the_file, s))
    {
        lines.push_back(s);
    }

for(int i=0; i < sizeof(lines)/sizeof(lines); i++)

   {

       cout << lines[i] << endl;

   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`lines.size()` will return the length of a vector. So use

```
for(int i=0; i < lines.size(); i++) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`sizeof(lines)/sizeof(lines)` will return 1, which means the loop is going to run just once.

an `std::vector` has a `size()` method, you can use that:

```
for(int i=0; i < lines.size(); i++)
```

You can also use the range based for if you're using atleast C++11:

```
for(auto value : lines)
{
  cout << value << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your program prints only first line of the file since `sizeof(lines)/sizeof(lines)` is 1 and the `for` loop will run once printing just `lines[0]`. You have to go through all elements of `lines` vector to print all elements. To do so, the `for` loop should be like this: 
`for(int i=0; i< lines.size(); i++){ cout<<lines[i]<<endl; }`